# How to prevent div move to a next line during jQuery animation effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 6 small circles live in `div` with class `.col-sm-2`
I tried to apply the shake effect to my next div, but CSS seems to move my div to a new line during the jQuery shake effect.

---

## HTML

```
<div class="row text-center ">
    <div class="col-sm-2 client">
        <span class="fa fa-mobile circle-icon fa-5x"></span>
        <div class="options">
            <p class="option" id="MBNPrivate">MBNPrivate</p>
            <p class="option" id="SPWifiCmst">SPWifiCmst</p>
            <p class="option" id="GuestCmst">GuestCmst</p>
        </div>
        <div class="selected"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 agent">
        <span class="fa fa-bicycle circle-icon fa-5x"></span>
        <div class="options">
            <p class="option" id="BenuAgent1">BenuAgent1</p>
            <p class="option" id="BenuAgent1">BenuAgent1</p>
            <p class="option" id="CTAgent">CTAgent</p>
        </div>
        <div class="selected"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

## CSS

```
option {
    font-style: 14px !important;
}

.circle-icon {
    background: #8B8A8B;
    padding:70px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin:30px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

p.option {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 15px;

}

p.option:hover {
    border: 3px solid white;
}

div.selected {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    background: #FBC800;
    padding: 15px;

}
```

---

## JS - jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $('div.options').hide();
    $('div.selected').hide();
    $('div.col-sm-2').hide();
    $('div.col-sm-2').fadeIn(5000);

    $('.fa-mobile').click(function() {

        let self = $(this);

        $('div.options').fadeOut('fast');
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#4BB7E8" }, 1400);
        $(this).next('.options').slideDown(1000);

        $(this).next('.options').click(function(event) {
            let selectedText = event.target.id;
            console.log(selectedText);
            $(this).slideUp("slow", function() {
                $(this).next('.selected').text(selectedText).fadeIn(3000);
                $('.agent').effect( "shake", { direction: "up", times: 2, distance: 10}, 1000 );
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

**How do I stop this ?**

[image]

Comment: Could you possibly set up a CodePly, as your custom CSS is not in this post. Not sure if thats why, but I can't replicate on my end.

Comment: I added the CSS parts. Meanwhile, I will try to do that on fiddle and share.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work but in your example HTML the first class is a `.row` this will mess up some resposiveness/stacking. Make sure you have the `.row` in one of the following: `.container`, `.container-fluid`, `.col`